# alignat with bolded line numbers

Tags: formatting, numbering, bold, alignat

```
$$
\begin{alignat}{5}
2c_1&\;+\;&5c_2 &\;=\;& 1\\
-c_1&&&\;=\;&-8\\
3c_1&\;+\;&4c_2&\;=\;&12
\end{alignat}
$$
```

The above automatically labels the lines (1), (2) and (3) but I want **(1)**, **(2)** and **(3)**.

Comment: See [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Comment: in this case, the `$$` are entirely unnecessary and unwanted; the `alignat` environment is a multi-line display structure that's automatically in display math mode.  i'm rather surprised that no warning (or error) resulted.

Answer (score 2):

Below I've updated `\maketag@@@` to insert `\tagfont` that you can manipulate via `\renewcommand`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont\tagfont#1}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\tagfont}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{5}
  2c_1&\;+\;&5c_2 &\;=\;& 1\\
  -c_1&&&\;=\;&-8\\
  3c_1&\;+\;&4c_2&\;=\;&12
\end{alignat}

\renewcommand{\tagfont}{\bfseries}
\begin{alignat}{5}
  2c_1 & {}+{} & 5c_2 & {}={} &  1 \\
  -c_1 &       &      & {}={} & -8 \\
  3c_1 & {}+{} & 4c_2 & {}={} & 12 \label{abc}
\end{alignat}
\renewcommand{\tagfont}{}

See~\eqref{abc}.
\end{document}
```

The first `alignat` keeps your original format, while the second is a little more reader-friendly and uses the natural spacing around operators and operands rather than a forced `\;`.

Answer (score 2):

You can define tag styles with the `\newtagform` and `\usetagform` commands, from the `mathtools` package. I also simplified your code; actually, you have only three alignment points (remmember that k alignment points normally require 2k – 1 ampersands). On another hand, you have a correct horizontal spacing adding `{}` rather than `\;`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newtagform{bf}{\bfseries(}{)}

\begin{document}

\usetagform{bf}

\begin{alignat}{3}
2c_1&+{}&5c_2 & = {}& 1\\
-c_1&&& = &-8\\
3c_1& + &4c_2& = &12
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]